# Example of custom NSSharingService window

Tags: cocoa, appkit

It seems to be possible to customize the NSWindow used by an NSSharingService.  Does anybody know of any examples where this has been done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sharingServicePicker:sharingServicesForItems:proposedSharingServices:` of the delegate (that should conform `NSSharingServicePickerDelegate protocol).

This gives you a reference to the NSSharingServicePicker object just before it's presented to the user, so you can customize it there.